# How to disable picture-in-picture in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, video

Last month, probably in Firefox 66, a new feature showed up - picture in picture video. Now when I exit a YouTube tab playing a video and go somewhere else on the website, the previous video hangs in the lower right corner of the screen, and if I hadn't paused the video, it plays.

This is obnoxious and I'd like to disable the feature. I've looked online, but the [flag](http://browserengine.net/mozilla-working-on-firefox-picture-in-picture-mode/) from `about:config` that was used to enable PIP in beta, `media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.enabled` doesn't seem to exist anymore.

Are there any ways to disable it? Given the fact it's now a [WebAPI draft](https://wicg.github.io/picture-in-picture/), more websites could implement it, so solutions that aren't YT specific are preferable.

Comment: Hmm. "As of this writing, you need to install the latest build of **Firefox Nightly** in order to try the feature in action. " and "Please keep in mind that Picture-in-Picture mode in Firefox is a work-in-progress as of now. It may not work reliably and doesn't have many customizable settings or features." from [Firefox is Getting Picture-in-Picture Mode](https://winaero.com/blog/firefox-is-getting-picture-in-picture-mode/)

Comment: "it's now a standard WebAPI" No it isn't. It's still a draft.

Comment: I am not using Firefox Nightly. I am using Firefox 66.0.3 from Ubuntu 16.04 repositories

Comment: Indeed. What you are seeing is **not** Firefox's PIP but Youtube's PIP. Other sites such as https://www.dailymail.co.uk/home/index.html also have a similar annoyance where scrolling the page causes an embedded vid to go PIP. It is not Firefox causing it.

Comment: Mine is also broken, where the blue icon sticks around on some videos and does not go away.

I have the `media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.enabled` flag in Firefox Developer 69.0b1, but turning it off does nothing.

Comment: This is still a valid question and it doesn't have anything to do with Firefox. I have exactly the same, annoying problem in Safari on macOS.

Answer (score 7):

To hide the button just right click it and click hide. You won't see it anymore.

Comment: This leaves it up to the site to determine how it wants to handle your action.  In the case of YouTube, hiding this video is not permanent.  I think the OP is asking for a way for the user to unilaterally and permanently disable it across all sites, without regard to how any particular website wants to handle it.

Answer (score 3):

I see the same thing. In about:config, setting `media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.enabled` to false doesn't do much, but setting `media.videocontrols.picture-in-picture.video-toggle.enabled` to false as well seems to do the job. Tested in Firefox 71 beta.

Comment: Doesn't work in Firefox 70 Stable, but I'll wait for the update and hope you're right

Comment: This works in FF 78 but unfortunately the keyboard shortcut still activates it. I logged the following bug: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1645586